# Polymer core-list delete item

Tags: polymer

How could I remove an Item in a core-list or clear the list?

I retrieve my list from a Database. When I select an Item, the Item would be deleted in the Database and my list refreshed.

But the last Item could not deleted, because my list doesn' t refresh without an entry in the Database.

How could I remove the last entry.

```
<core-list 
  on-core-activate="{{selectBookedItem}}"
  id="listNewBookedItems"
  data="{{ajaxResponseBookedItem}}">
  <template>
    <div id="bbb" class="newBookedItem {{ {selected: selected} | tokenList }}">
           <div id="itemFontSmall">Preis: {{artikelpreis}}</div>
    </div>
  </template>
</core-list>

Polymer('element-posmain', {
  // Remove Code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ajaxResponseBookedItem is observable then you should be able to just remove the item from the list that corresponds to ajaxResponseBookedItem and core-list should pick it up. Ie remove from the model and let the view update itself

This works for me at least in the dart version